# Error en mi código de Django en la parte de models.py

Tags: python, django, django-models, cms

Rstoy aprendiendo a realizar modelos en django. Pero cuando estoy intentando hacer las migraciones me sale un mensaje de error conforme la parte de owner tiene un error en `get_full_name` de la primera clase y también en el return de la clase movie.

Los errores que salen son los siguientes: module `'django.db.models'` has no attribute 'SET_CASCADE', pero también sale que entre la linea 23,20 el `ForeignKey` has no `'get_full_name'` member y que tanto rate como rate_ count no estan como variables definidas.Dejo aquí el código.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator
User= get_user_model()`

class MoveList(models.Model):
    #modelo de lista para ver
    name= models.CharField('Nombre de la Lista', max_length=50, unique=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    movies = models.ManyToManyField('movies.Movie')


    # como se va a mostrar el objeto
    def __str__(self):
        return "'{list}' de {owner}".format(
            list =self.name,
            owner =self.owner.get_full_name()
        )

class Movie(models.Model):
    #Modelo de peliculas
    name= models.CharField('Nombre de la pelicula',max_length=100)
    release_date = models.DateField('Fecha de estreno')
    rate = models.PositiveIntegerField('Total de claificaciones de la pelicula',blank=True, null=True)
    rate_count = models.PositiveIntegerField('Veces que se ha calificado a la pelicula',blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('movies.Tag')
    studio = models.ForeignKey ('movies.Studio',on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    director =models.ForeignKey('movies.Director',on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)`

    def average_rate(self):
        """"devuelve la calificación"""
        #evitar un error de division por cero
        if self.rate_count == 0:
            return 0
        else:
            return rate/rate_count

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: si muestras el mensaje de error te podriamos ayudar rápidamente :)

Comment: sale esto init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete' pero también sale que entre la linea 23,20 el ForeignKey has no 'get_full_name' member y que tanto rate como rate_ count no estan como variables definidas

Comment: Rocio edita tu pregunta y añadelo alli :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero con las nuevas versiones de Django es obligatorio añadir el argumento on_delete en los FK de los modelos, por ejemplo:

```
studio = models.ForeignKey ('movies.Studio', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

O

```
studio = models.ForeignKey ('movies.Studio', on_delete=models.SET_CASCADE)
```

con este parámetro se indica la acción que se debe de llevar acabó cuando un registro que es FK de otro se elimina.

Segundo la función str se debe declarar con dos guiones, por ejemplo:

```
def __str__(self): 
       ...
       ...
```